# String not specified

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to create a program with a bunch of different classes.  Somehow, despite the fact that `#include < string>` has been used multiple times, I am still getting missing type specifier errors.

I have no idea where is is.  Does anyone know where this problem might originate, or if not any steps I could take to try and debug this problem?

I'm sorry about the long post, I just didn't want to leave anything out.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ATP.cpp"
#include "AtlasObject.cpp"
#include "MAP.cpp"
#include "AtlasObjectFactory.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

AtlasObject.cpp:

```
#ifndef ATLASOBJECT_CPP
#define ATLASOBJECT_CPP

#include <string>


class AtlasObject{

public:
    virtual void create();

protected:
    string uid;
    string label;
    int colorR;
    int colorB;
    int colorG;
    char *data;
    int isEncrypted;

    void set_uid(string id);
    void set_label(string l);
    void set_color(int r, int b, int g);
    void set_data(char* inData);
    void set_isEncrypted(int encrypted);

    string get_uid();
    string get_label();
    string get_color();
    vchar* get_data();
    int get_isEncrypted();
};

void AtlasObject::set_uid(string id) {}
void AtlasObject::set_label(string l) {}
void AtlasObject::set_color(int r, int b, int g) {}
void AtlasObject::set_data(char *inData) {}
void AtlasObject::set_isEncrypted(int encrypted) {}

string AtlasObject::get_uid() {}
string AtlasObject::get_label() {}
string AtlasObject::get_color() {}
char* AtlasObject::get_data() {}
int AtlasObject::get_isEncrypted() {}

#endif
```

AtlasObjectFactory.cpp:

```
#ifndef ATLASOBJECTFACTORY_CPP
#define ATLASOBJECTFACTORY_CPP
#include "AtlasObject.cpp"

class AtlasObjectFactory
{
public:
    static void getInstance();
    ~AtlasObjectFactory();
    AtlasObject* createObject(int obj_type);

private:
    AtlasObjectFactory();
};
#endif
```

ATP.cpp:

```
#ifndef ATP_CPP
#define ATP_CPP

#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "AtlasObject.cpp"

using namespace std;

struct Image{
    string Dim;
    string Vox;
    string Ori;
    char* data;
};

class APT
{
private:
    map<string,int> listOfMaps;
    Image referenceImage;

protected:
};
#endif // AtlasObject.cpp
```

MAP.cpp:

```
#ifndef MAP_CPP
#define MAP_CPP

#include "AtlasObject.cpp"

class MAP : public AtlasObject
{
public:
    void create();
};
void MAP::create()
{
}
#endif
```

Comment: You need to refer to it as `std::string`. And beware of using the `.cpp` extension for header files, your IDE might try to compile them automatically.

Comment: Why do you do you include `cpp` files ? why do you use `cpp` files for writing header stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your AtlasObject.cpp file, you should add this:

```
using std::string;
```

Since `std::string` is created under the namespace `std` and you have no `using namespace std` specified.

Comment: Thank you, that cleared up 109 of my 120 errors :P

The other 11 seem to be in my ATP file, I'll see what I can do about fixing them.